# Imaginary first introduction $\arg (1+i)$

Tags: calculus

I have been asked to find $$\arg (1+i)$$

This is how I reason; since I know that $$\left| 1+i\right| =\sqrt{2}$$

I know that the hypotenuse is equal to $\sqrt{2}$ and I know that adjacent is equal to 1. I therefore find that opposite(x) is equal to $$\left\{x\to \sqrt{2-1}\right\}$$,

However I do not get what the arg really means and why the answer should be $\frac{\pi }{4}$,

Could someone show me what it means by taking example above and the case of $$\arg (-1+i)=\frac{3 \pi }{4}$$

Comment: Your "opposite" length is incorrect. It should be $\sqrt{2 - 1} = 1$. Indeed, you don't need to calculate it at all: it's simply the imaginary part of $1+i$. The argument is simply the angle between $1+i$ and the positive real axis. If you plot the point $1+i$ and draw the line segment between this point and the origin, the slope of the line segment is $1$, which corresponds to an angle of $\pi/4$.

Comment: Oh how stupid of me,  then it makes more sense.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea to locate your complex number in the plane, i.e. draw it. Then the {\italic basic angle} say $\theta$ can be determined for $z=a+ib$, for example by observing that $tan (\theta )=b/a$ or otherwise. But note that the $Arg(z)$ is not $arctan(b/a)$ for complex numbers outside first and forth quadrants. The $Arg(z)$ (principal argument) is taken in $(-\pi ,\pi]$ and it is deduced from the basic angle and the location of $z$ in the complex plane (drawing a picture helps here).